# How to use the Generic Type of a Types Property?

Tags: swift, xcode, generics, swiftui, functional-programming

**Context**

I have a `SwiftUI` `View` which gets initialised with a `ViewModel` (`Observable Object`). This `ViewModel` itself has a `Generic Type`.
I am now trying to use the `Generic Type` of the `ViewModel` inside the `View` itself, however, can't get hold of it.

---

**Code**

```swift
class ComponentViewModel<C: Component>: ObservableObject { ... }

struct SomeView: View {
    @ObservedObject var componentVM: ComponentViewModel

    init(with componentVM: ComponentViewModel) {
        componentVM = componentVM
    }

    var body: some View {
        switch componentVM.C.self { ... } // This does not work.
    }
```

---

**Question**

- How can I use the `Generic Type` of `Types Property`, in this case of `componentVM`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your View generic as well

```
struct SomeView<ModelType: Component>: View
```

and then you use `ModelType` in your code to refer to the generic type of the view model

```
struct SomeView<ModelType: Component>: View {
    @ObservedObject var componentVM: ComponentViewModel<ModelType>

    init(with componentVM: ComponentViewModel<ModelType>) {
        self.componentVM = componentVM
    }

    var body: some View {
        switch ModelType.self {
        //...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your componentVM like that:

```
@ObservedObject var componentVM: ComponentViewModel<SomeSolideType>
```

SomeSolidType should be some class / struct conforming to your Component protocol.